# $(\infty,1)$-topoi generated by $(n,1)$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, terminology, infinity-topos-theory

A (1,1)-topos (i.e. an ordinary Grothendieck topos) is called *localic* if the following two equivalent conditions hold:

- It is the category of sheaves on a (0,1)-site with finite limits$^*$ (i.e. a meet-semilattice with a Grothendieck topology).
- It is a left exact localization of the category of presheaves on a (0,1)-category with finite limits (= a meet-semilattice).

The category of localic topoi is reflective in the category of all topoi, and equivalent to the category of locales.

For $0\le m\le n \le \infty$, *Higher topos theory* 6.4.5.7-8 shows that an $(n,1)$-topos is *$m$-localic* iff the analogue of the first condition holds: it is the category of $(n-1)$-sheaves on an $(m,1)$-site with finite limits.  In 6.4.5.9 it is remarked that this is equivalent to it being a *topological* localization of the category of $\infty$-presheaves on an $(m,1)$-category with finite limits.  The category of $m$-localic $(n,1)$-topoi is reflective in all $(n,1)$-topoi, and equivalent to the category of $(m,1)$-topoi.

When $n<\infty$, every localization of an $(n,1)$-topos is topological, so the two conditions are still equivalent, but this fails when $n=\infty$.  So what can be said about the larger class of $(\infty,1)$-topoi that are merely a *left exact* localization of $\infty$-presheaves on some $(m,1)$-category with finite limits?  I believe this is equivalently the class of cotopological localizations of $m$-localic $(\infty,1)$-topoi, or the class of $(\infty,1)$-topoi that have a generating set consisting of $(m-1)$-truncated objects.  Does it have a name?  Has it been studied?

$^*$ **Edit:** In the original version of this question I omitted the assumption of finite limits.  This is irrelevant when $n<\infty$ but makes a difference when $n=\infty$; see the comments.  I do want to ask about the case where finite limits are assumed, so I edited the question.

Comment: Is it really true that presheaves on a $n$-category form an $n$-localic $\infty$-topos? The statement in HTT assumes that the $n$-category has finite limits.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Good question.  It's true when $n=0$, right?  I would be surprised if it weren't true; I assumed the assumption of finite limits was just to avoid talking about flat functors.

Comment: If it's not true, then I would also want to assume finite limits for the class I'm interested in.

Comment: Since $(n-1)$-truncated objects are stable under finite limits, if we restrict ourselves to hypercomplete $(\infty,1)$-topoi, it looks like being $n$-localic really means being an hypercomplete left exact localization of a category of presheaves on an $(n,1)$-category. In particular, presheaves of $\infty$-groupoids on a $(n,1)$-category form a hypercomplete $(\infty,1)$-topos generated by its $(n-1)$-truncated objects and thus define a $n$-localic topos.

Comment: It seems that it fails even when $n=0$: there is [an example of Charles Rezk](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52487042#52487042) of a topological space whose hypercomplete sheaves are presheaves on a poset, so that the latter cannot be $n$-localic for any finite $n$. So it seems "flatness" for functors to $\infty$-topoi is strictly stronger than for $n$-topoi, which is similar to what happens with "dense" subsites.

Comment: @MarcHoyois How do you conclude that it can't be $n$-localic?

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski What do you mean by "restrict ourselves to hypercomplete $(\infty,1)$-topoi"?  Certainly an $n$-localic topos need not be hypercomplete?

Comment: Yes, localic $n$-topoi need to be hypercomplete. What I meant is that we can characterize $n$-localic $\infty$-topoi as those hypercomplete $\infty$-topoi that are generated by their $(n-1)$-truncated objects (but a general $\infty$-topos generated by its truncated objects need not be hypercomplete). I also meant that Marc's concerns about having a site with finite limits are not really important because we restrict ourselves to hypercomplete topoi anyway.

Comment: If $Shv(X)^{hyp}$ is $n$-localic then it must agree with $Shv(X)$ since they have the same $(n-1)$-truncated objects and the latter is $0$-localic. But in Rezk's example $Shv(X)$ is not hypercomplete.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Thanks, I see!

Comment: @D.-C.Cisinski I still don't understand what you're saying.  I said that an $n$-localic topos may NOT be hypercomplete.  Rezk's example cited by Marc shows this.

Comment: One interesting observation about these "weakly $m$-localic" topoi is that (I think) the collection of them all is an $(m,2)$-category, like the collection of $m$-localic topoi.

Comment: $n$-localic topoi are not hypercomplete, but we can still define "$n$-hyperlocalic topoi" as those $\infty$-topoi that are both hypercomplete and generated by their $(n-1)$-truncated objects (these are not $n$-localic topoi in the sense of HTT though). Then the operator $\tau_{\leq n-1}$ induces an equivalence from $n$-hyperlocalic topoi to $n$-topoi. This also implies that the assignment $X\mapsto X^\wedge$ defines an equivalence from $n$-localic topoi to $n$-hyperlocalic ones (that is far from being the identity, though).

Comment: What I meant is that the theory of $n$-hyperlocalic $\infty$-topoi is easier to understand because it behaves more like the theory of $n$-topoi (because $n$-topoi for finite $n$ are hypercomplete), in particular when it comes to finding sites of definition.